# AWS Aurora failover in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-aurora

I'm looking to gracefully handle AWS Aurora's failover mechanism in a Rails 6 app.

[Other solutions I've found](https://gist.github.com/matsukaz/fb0e0bc47752ebb6f751c79268e1b6f5) swap out a specific Rack middleware adapter with one that will reset all ActiveRecord connections if a specific type of exception is raised. **That middleware has been removed in Rails 6** so this solution no longer works.

The exception that gets raised is an `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid`: "PG::ReadOnlySqlTransaction: ERROR:  cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction".

Would the following be an idiomatic way to rescue this exception and reset the connection pool as needed?

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid, with: :check_read_only_failover

  private

  def check_read_only_failover(exception)
    if /Lost connection|gone away|read-only/.match?(exception.message)
      ActiveRecord::Base.clear_all_connections!
    end
  end
```

(The regex above was lifted from the linked solution; I have no reason to believe the error condition has changed.)

Comment: If you connect to the cluster instead of the instances directly, the failover should be seemless to the application.

Comment: @dbugger - I think the issue is that the writer endpoint gets repointed to the new writer instance using DNS; the old DNS value is cached by the application and so requests get routed incorrectly for a brief period.

Comment: In local testing, I saw the 'read only' error for a couple of minutes; an app restart fixed the problem (I guess as the app performs another DNS lookup when reconnecting the to the writer endpoint?)

Comment: @henryaj I'm currently facing the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?